# Is there another way to write this regex: [^|]+

Tags: sql, regex

When using REGEXP_SUBSTR function in sql such as  [^|]+, 1, 1  and string   'test1' | 'test2' | 'test3', the output result would be 'test1', however I am trying to find out if the pattern [^|]+ can be written in a different manner. Thanks

The select query works, however I was trying to find out if there is another expression more efficient that could replace the matching pattern: [^|]+ and show the same results

Comment: Why would you want to write it in a different manner? What's wrong with `[^|]+`? It is succinct and immediately transparent to anyone who understands the basics of regular expressions.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _if there is another expression more efficient_ What criteria do you use to determine the efficiency of a regular expression?

Comment: The first "performance issues" I look at in regexs, is backtracking (that could lead to DoS), and "eagerness". Your regex is so simple I don't think is vulnerable to any of those.

Comment: Apologies for not adding this upfront, my use case is that I am working with an old sql editor ( quite outdated) that is unable to parse this regex [^|]+ , and I was trying to find another pattern that is able to extract any character and exclude pipe | .

 If I have in a column the following entry: 
test123 : | test1234 - | test567 ? , using the  REGEXP_SUBSTR function I wanted to extract only let's say 
test123 : 
or 
test1234 -
etc.. of course this works perfectly with [^|]+, however the sql editor that I'm using is unable to parse using that pattern.

Comment: Did you try `[^\|]+` instead of `[^|]+` ? Some regex flavours want you to escape special chars even in character classes. For example, in JavaScript, both `[^|]` and `[^\|]` will work but only `[^\]]` would work to match any char not beeing a closing bracket. With PCRE, `[^]]` will work even so it is not escaped.

Comment: Thank you all for all the input. After some further debugging this seems not related to the regex pattern but more to some kind of outdated regex parser used by the sql editor. Again - I really appreciate all your comments and suggestions . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. What SQL engine are you running?
2. Is it really your editor which is the problem?

   I would imagine that `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` is a function given by
   your database server and not the editor. Is it *Oracle*?
   I see that *MariaDB* is running with PCRE's regex flavour, which is
   quite powerful. It's probably the same for *MySQL*. But your Regex
   flavour might not support the `[^|]+` notation and you may have to
   write it `[^\|]+` because the pipe char has to be escaped,
   depending on the engine.

I had a go with an example for your problem, on *MySQL* and *MariaDB*:

```sql
-- Create the table.
CREATE TABLE tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  tag TEXT NOT NULL,
  attributes TEXT NOT NULL,
  textContent TEXT,
  parentId INTEGER
);

-- Insert data into the table.
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (00, 'body', '', null, null);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (01, 'table', 'class="user-list"|id="users"', null, 0);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (02, 'tr', '', null, 1);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (03, 'th', 'class="firstname"', 'First name', 2);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (04, 'th', 'class="lastname"', 'Last name', 2);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (05, 'tr', 'id="user-007"|class="secret-agent permit-to-kill"', null, 1);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (06, 'td', 'class="firstname"', 'James', 5);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (07, 'td', 'class="lastname"', 'Bond', 5);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (08, 'tr', 'id="user-578"|class="animal"|style="background-color: yellow"', null, 1);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (09, 'td', 'class="firstname"', 'Mickey', 8);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (10, 'td', 'class="lastname"', 'Mouse', 8);

-- Fetch data and use regular expressions.
SELECT
  *,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(attributes, '[^\|]+$') AS lastAttribute,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(attributes, '(?<=class=")[^"]+(?=")') AS classAttribute
FROM
  tags;
```

You can run it here: https://onecompiler.com/mariadb/3zztbfat2

It actually works fine and returns this:

```
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| id | tag   | attributes                                                    | textContent | parentId | lastAttribute                       | classAttribute              |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  0 | body  |                                                               | NULL        |     NULL |                                     |                             |
|  1 | table | class="user-list"|id="users"                                  | NULL        |        0 | id="users"                          | user-list                   |
|  2 | tr    |                                                               | NULL        |        1 |                                     |                             |
|  3 | th    | class="firstname"                                             | First name  |        2 | class="firstname"                   | firstname                   |
|  4 | th    | class="lastname"                                              | Last name   |        2 | class="lastname"                    | lastname                    |
|  5 | tr    | id="user-007"|class="secret-agent permit-to-kill"             | NULL        |        1 | class="secret-agent permit-to-kill" | secret-agent permit-to-kill |
|  6 | td    | class="firstname"                                             | James       |        5 | class="firstname"                   | firstname                   |
|  7 | td    | class="lastname"                                              | Bond        |        5 | class="lastname"                    | lastname                    |
|  8 | tr    | id="user-578"|class="animal"|style="background-color: yellow" | NULL        |        1 | style="background-color: yellow"    | animal                      |
|  9 | td    | class="firstname"                                             | Mickey      |        8 | class="firstname"                   | firstname                   |
| 10 | td    | class="lastname"                                              | Mouse       |        8 | class="lastname"                    | lastname                    |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```